# JavaScriptでストレージに記録できない。

Tags: javascript

ストレージに記録できない。
サンプルコードの文法が読解できず、キーとバリューをどのように記述するのか分かっていないと思うのですが、ブラウザのインスペクタを見ても、ローカルストレージに全然記録されないので、何が間違っているのか分からないのです。

**manifest**

```
"permissions": ["storage","activeTab","tabs"],
```

**contents script**

```js
var pref=["a","b","c"]; // valueの配列
pref=browser.storage.local.set({key:"pref"});
```

Answer (score 0):

以下の様にコードを修正してください。

```js
var pref = ["a", "b", "c"];
browser.storage.local.set({ "key": pref });
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事、記録する事が出来ました。お礼を言うのが遅れたのは、拡張機能のストレージは、Firefoxの通常のインスペクタ画面ではなく、デバッガーランタイムのページで調査というボタンを押して確認をするのを知らず、延々と無駄に悩み続けてしまいました。何日も同じところで出来なかったので、ありがとうございます。本当に助かりました。